# Linking two tables in one through foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I´m trying to link two tables into one reference table,so I took the primary keys of students and programs and placed them in the table classStudent so I can relate a student with a program, but I keep getting the error:

> Cannot add or update a child row:a foreign key constraint
>   fails(`CRSDB`.`classStudent`,CONSTRAINT `classStudent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN
>   KEY(`programs_ID`)REFERENCE`programs`(`ID`)ON DELETE NO ACTION ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION).

PLEASE any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CRSDB`.`students` (
  `ID` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CRSDB`.`programs` (
  `ID` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CRSDB`.`classStudent` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `class_ID` INT NULL,
  `programs_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `students_ID` DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `fk_classStudent_programs1_idx` (`programs_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_classStudent_students1_idx` (`students_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_classStudent_programs`
    FOREIGN KEY (`programs_ID`)
    REFERENCES `CRSDB`.`programs` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_classStudent_students`
    FOREIGN KEY (`students_ID`)
    REFERENCES `CRSDB`.`students` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: This is what JOINs and VIEWs are for.

Comment: thank you @Crowcoder for the answer, how can I use that to insert the information in my classStudent table without getting the constraint error?

Comment: apologies, I should be more clear. I mean that you don't need to create a third table, it is poor design. You are duplicating data and creating maintenance overhead. I suggest you write a VIEW or use a query that JOINs the tables to obtain the information you want.

Comment: ok, understand, but in this case it is the way in how i permanently relate a student with a program of study, i don´t do it in the table of student because if the student change the area of studies I still can have records of the change of program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to add a value to the `classStudent` table you have to have valid records in both the `students` and `programs` table.

If your `students` table looks like this:

```
ID     Name
----  ----------
1      George
2      Samuel
```

And your `programs` table looks like this

```
ID     Name
----  ----------
1      History
2      Science
```

You can only add values to the `classStudent` table that match the ID's of the foreign key fields:

```
ID     class_ID   programs_ID   students_ID
----  ---------- ------------- -------------
1      ?          1             1
2      ?          1             2
3      ?          2             1
4      ?          2             3   <====WILL FAIL
```

I don't know what the `class_ID` field is supposed to be, but I don't see a constraint on it.

Since those column values are dependent on the other tables values, you cannot add a value that doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, students and programs do have valid  information but at the moment I run the query :"INSERT INTO classStudent (students_ID, programs_ID) VALUES(1,1)"; i get the error.

Comment: @das And you are absolutely certain that there is a record in the `programs` table with the ID of 1?

Comment: is it necessary or even possible to use inner join when inserting into the table?

Comment: @das If you run the query "SELECT * FROM programs WHERE ID=1;" and "SELECT* FROM students WHERE ID=1;" you get a result back for both?

Comment: i get the result on both tables that`s why i have been dealing with this problem all day and I don´t get where is the error. it does not allow me to insert information in this foreign key field.

Comment: @das Question: I see `classStudent_ibfk_1` in the error, but I don't see it in the definition ??? Did you change something in the structure or column names since the error?

Comment: I noticed that by "disabling FK checks for inserts" I can now insert information directly using the server with warnings in return, but i can finally insert. Now that i try to insert from my c# windows application i continue getting the error. Any idea why?

Comment: @das I have a theory. I noticed that the ID columns on programs and students are nullable fields and are not set as the primary key. Set both to NOT NULL and make them primary keys. Then try your inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the most adecuate or secure way to solve this issue but something that worked for me was creating a small method to set the foreign key check to 0, and after inserting the information set it back to 1. I hope this can help someone.
This code is in c#:

```
public void disableCHECK()
{
 conexion.Open();
 if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
  {
   string query = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0";
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   this.CloseConnection();
  }
}
```